# Как скрыть папку с аватрами(изображения) от прямого доступа?

Tags: php, файлы, .htaccess, upload

Изображения сохраняются в директорию `images/`. Можно ли как то запретить прямой доступ по url, но дать возможность выводить с помощью тега img?
Я думал над альтернативным способом, но не уверен реализуемо ли, хранить картинки на уровень выше корня сайта. С помощью header заголовков получать изображения, преобразовать в base64 и отдавать клиенту в тег img.

Comment: Я, конечно бы, предложил хранить все смайлы в одном массиве (аля спрайт) в base64, и отрисовывать их по надобности через canvas. Но для вас это будет слишком сложно. Причем, сам массив можно зашифровать. Самое простое - через XOR по времени запроса/ответа странички + время начала сессии. Это чтобы если страницу сохранили, ключ остался несохраненным. В любом случае, если захотят заиметь ваши смайлы, это остановит только нубов. Если более изощренно подходить к делу, то временный ключ для расшифровки можно получать отдельными токенами.

Comment: @DiD вроде речь про аватарки а не про смайлы.

Comment: @Ипатьев, аа ну да, тогда все не сохранишь. А зачем аватарки защищать? Они же пользовательские!

Comment: @DiD ну в головах у новичков часто бывают странные идеи. Они часто кидаются защищать то что никому не нужно или оптимизировать то что не тормозит

Comment: Не вижу смысла в этом... Но, как вариант, хранить картинки в хранилище которое не залинковано на доступ по http(s) сделать отдельный роут который будет проверять куки, и если есть соответствующая запись то отдавать картинку если нет то отдавать заглушку... Но при этом любой кто получил эту запись в куки(а её же можно получить тем же курлом) будет видеть картинки... Не вижу смысла в подобном извращении

Answer (score 4):

> Можно ли как то запретить прямой доступ по url, но дать возможность выводить с помощью тега img?

Нельзя.

Какой-то особенный "прямой доступ" - это очень распространенное суеверие.  В реальности же никакого "кривого доступа" не существует.

#### C точки зрения сервера, ВСЕ обращения к нему - "прямые"

И запретив "прямое" ты просто запретишь любые обращения вообще.

Поэтому любые фантазии про "закрыть прямой доступ но позволить бразуеру запрашивать" не имеют смысла.

Надо купить книжку Котерова, РНР7, и прочитать с самого начала. Там даются основы протокола НТТР, как раз для таких вот самоучек, которые всё изучают методом тыка.

Если же тебе нужно отдавать какую-то информацю в зависимости от каких-то **условий** (например только авторизованным пользователям), то именно такой вопрос и надо задавать. В этом случае вариант "хранить выше корня сайта и отдавать скриптом" вполне подойдет

Comment: Извини, ты обычно пишешь довольно грамотные вещи, за исключением мелких косяков, но сейчас тебя куда-то совсем не в ту сторону унесло. Повторяю специально для тебя: для сервера **все** обращения "прямые". Даже через "CURL". А "ухищрения" о которых ты говоришь относятся не к "прямому доступу" а к решению каких-то других задач, про которые в вопросе ничего не было.

Comment: Я понял. тут должны быть только ВАШИ ответы - только они правильные. Судя по тому как Вы их накручиваете и минусите другие. Что ж, ивзините не знал, свои удалил. Помогать больше никому не буду.

Comment: странная реакция, но хозяин-барин. в целом уровень твоих ответов сильно выше той белиберды, которую тут пишут обычно. надо только внимательнее относиться к замечаниям. ладно я пишу намеками, но sercxjo открытым текстом написал про 404. но с таким отношением, "ах, мне смеют делать замечания? вообще ничего не буду писать!" действительно не стоит никому помогать

Comment: Все обращения прямые, допустим. Но авторизацию прикрутить же никто не мешает) Реклама книжки какой-то ещё... 
 Последний абзац в ответе, впрочем, отвечает на вопрос ТС. Держи плюсик)